# Excel row-wise multiplication

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to multiply, row-by-row, two columns in an Excel sheet (in order to take the median of the resulting column).

```
1  3
2  5
4  2
```

Should become

```
3
10
8
```

How can I do that in a formula (i.e. without creating a separate column with the multiplication result)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want an *array formula*...

Assuming your data starts in A1, you can type:

```
=MEDIAN(A1:A3*B1:B3)
```

and the press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter it into the cell as an *array formula*. If you do it correctly, you'll see the formula enclosed in curly braces by Excel.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know you had t use ctrl+shift+enter for that.

Answer (score 0):

In excel, you can multiply cells together in the median formula to get the result.

The median of {3, 10, 8} = 8 in excel you can use Median(A1*B1, A2*B2, A3*B3) to get the same result.  Provided the first number "1" starts on A1.