# Product of cells corresponding to their rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I read from [this](https://superuser.com/q/155238/539529) question how to obtain the median for a given dataset after calculating the product of the arrays.

However, in intend to find the product of each pair of corresponding cells that'll then be shown in a third column. The dataset I have is huge and I hope there is a faster way to do this than finding the product of each pair to add in the third cell.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the accepted answer of the question =MEDIAN(A1:A3*B1:B3)
array formula(press Ctrl+Shift+Enter) no need for a third column

Comment: It repeats the product of the first pair of cells and that is my problem

Comment: You have to write your references =MEDIAN(A1:A1000*B1:B1000) and do not drag it just in one cell you will have the Result for all pair

Comment: If you only need the product use =Product(A1:B1) and drag it down

Comment: I'll try that the soonest and give feedback after.